# How does one use the aeson-schema package?

Tags: haskell, aeson

**aeson-schema** is a package for validating JSON-data against a JSON-schema.
Has anyone an example of how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a basic example [in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/aeson-schema/0.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-Aeson-Schema.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have a full working example in my question here:
[In aeson-schemas how do you construct an Object of a SchemaType without encoding to text and decoding back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59122804/154527)

> ```hs
> #!/usr/bin/env stack
> {- stack
>     runghc
>     --resolver lts-14.15
>     --package aeson-schemas-1.0.3
>     --package aeson
>     --package text
> -}
> {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
> {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
>
> import Data.Aeson (object, (.=), Value, decode, encode)
> import Data.Aeson.Schema
> import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
> import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
> import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
> import Data.Text(Text)
> import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)
>
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = do
>   let example = makeExample $ object [ "example" .= ("Example" :: Text) ]
>   useExample example
>
>
> useExample :: Object Example -> IO ()
> useExample example = T.putStrLn $ toStrict $ encodeToLazyText $ object [
>     "example" .= [get| example.example|]
>   ]
>
> makeExample :: Value -> Object Example
> makeExample = fromJust . decode . encode
>
>
> type Example = [schema|
>   {
>     example: Text,
>   }
> |]
> ```

More complex data structures including those with nullable values in objects are supported as well.

Here's an example from https://httpbin.org/json:

```
{
  "slideshow": {
    "author": "Yours Truly",
    "date": "date of publication",
    "slides": [
      {
        "title": "Wake up to WonderWidgets!",
        "type": "all"
      },
      {
        "items": [
          "Why <em>WonderWidgets</em> are great",
          "Who <em>buys</em> WonderWidgets"
        ],
        "title": "Overview",
        "type": "all"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Sample Slide Show"
  }
}
```

The **items** key within **slides** has a nullable value (it can be left out or defined as null) in the example.

Here's how to represent that JSON using aeson-schemas:

```hs
type Slideshow = [schema|
  {
    slideshow: {
      author: Text,
      date: Text,
      slides: List {
        title: Text,
        type: Text,
        items: Maybe List Text
      },
      title: Text
    }
  }
|]
```

Note `items: Maybe List Text` for handling the nullable/optional **items** key.

Here's a full working example for pulling JSON from the httpbin.org example and printing out JSON with just the author.

Create a file **print-author** with the following content:

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    runghc
    --resolver lts-14.15
    --package aeson-schemas-1.0.3
    --package aeson
    --package text
    --package req
-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Aeson (object, (.=), Value, decode, encode)
import Data.Aeson.Schema
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Text(Text)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)
import Network.HTTP.Req


main :: IO ()
main = do
  slideshow <- loadSlideshow
  useSlideshow slideshow


loadSlideshow :: IO (Object Slideshow)
loadSlideshow =
  runReq defaultHttpConfig $ do
    r <- req GET
      (https "httpbin.org" /: "json")
      NoReqBody
      jsonResponse
      mempty
    return (responseBody r)


useSlideshow :: Object Slideshow -> IO ()
useSlideshow slideshow =
  T.putStrLn $ toStrict $ encodeToLazyText $ object [
    "author" .= [get| slideshow.slideshow.author|]
  ]


type Slideshow = [schema|
  {
    slideshow: {
      author: Text,
      date: Text,
      slides: List {
        title: Text,
        type: Text,
        items: Maybe List Text
      },
      title: Text
    }
  }
|]
```

Make it executable:

```sh
chmod +x print-author
```

Run it:

```sh
./print-author
```

You should get the following output from the program:

```
{"author":"Yours Truly"}
```