# In aeson-schemas how do you construct an Object of a SchemaType without encoding to text and decoding back?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm using [aeson-schemas-1.0.3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-schemas-1.0.3) and I want to construct values of **Object Example** without round-tripping through an external serialized representation. It seems like a hack and I'm worried about the performance impact.

I have this schema defined:

```hs
type Example = [schema|
  {
    example: Text,
  }
|]
```

I want to be able to write something like this:

```hs
coerceJson $ object [ "example" .= ("Example" :: Text) ]
```

I have a workaround which does allow that, but it involves encoding to a ByteString and decoding to the Object of the desired SchemaType, which seems expensive and inelegant:

```hs
coerceJson :: FromJSON a => Value -> a
coerceJson = fromJust . decode . encode
```

This seems terribly inefficient.

Here's an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://www.sscce.org/) with my hack workaround employed. It works, but I'm convinced there's a better solution.

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    runghc
    --resolver lts-14.15
    --package aeson-schemas-1.0.3
    --package aeson
    --package text
-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Aeson (decode, encode, object, (.=), FromJSON, Value)
import Data.Aeson.Schema
import Data.Aeson.Text (encodeToLazyText)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Text(Text)
import Data.Text.Lazy (toStrict)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let example = coerceJson $ object [ "example" .= ("Example" :: Text) ]
  useExample example


useExample :: Object Example -> IO ()
useExample example = T.putStrLn $ toStrict $ encodeToLazyText $ object [
    "example" .= [get| example.example|]
  ]

coerceJson :: FromJSON a => Value -> a
coerceJson = fromJust . decode . encode


type Example = [schema|
  {
    example: Text,
  }
|]
```

In aeson-schemas how do you construct an Object of a SchemaType without encoding to text and decoding back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of `aeson-schemas`. There is currently no way to make a literal `Object`. The issue with what you're trying to do is, how do you know that the literal `Object` matches the schema? It's possible I could make an `unsafeObject` quasiquoter that would assume the object matches the schema you type it as.

I know this is old, but if you're still having problems with this, what exactly is your use-case? Often times, you'll be loading JSON data from an external source, like an API or a file.

Comment: My use case is to generate JSON requests to an API. What I'm looking for is a way to directly construct a value of type **Object Example** in code. The only way I could find was roundtripping the through a text encoding and parsing it back. In a sense I'd like a function `object' :: ToObject a => a -> Object a` where instances of **ToObject** could possibly be derived or manually coded.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer here, Brandon. My use case is creating values of type **Object Example** directly without having the external representation. I think the `unsafeObject` suggestion is a interesting one. `fromJust` is an ugly hack on my part here. Would `schemaObject :: Value -> Maybe (Object a)` be a reasonable choice here?

Comment: Why are you using aeson-schemas for sending JSON data? It's primarily useful for parsing JSON data. Why not just use `toJSON` instead of your proposed `object'` function? I'm still confused about how `schemaObject` would be useful in this use-case. Regardless, `schemaObject` is not too difficult to define yourself: `schemaObject = parseMaybe parseJSON`. Maybe open an issue in the aeson-schemas github page?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at how I was using it. I appreciate your engagement here. If this need arises again, I'll think it through and post up a proposal on the GitHub repo :)